# lxml returns empty list

Tags: python, lxml

I have seen many solutions on the internet, but non of them seem to work.

I have this code to retrieve information from a user in Imdb:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/user/ur6447592/comments-expanded?start=0&order=alpha')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

result = tree.xpath('//*[@id="outerbody"]/tbody/tr/td/b[2]/text()')

print(result)
```

The output should be:

```
["Little flesh and all bones"]
```

Comment: you could also skip a step and just `tree = html.parse('http://...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change xpath argument to:

```
'//*[@id="outerbody"]/tr/td/b[2]/text()'
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to the comments, I just realized why OP encountered the problem.

You can print `page.content` to see the original html. (via [@JacobIRR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555171/lxml-returns-empty-list/44555406?noredirect=1#comment76101452_44555406))

Or, in Firefox, Tools - Web Developer - Page Source.

In Google Chrome Developer Tools, as is quoted from [@corn3lius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555171/lxml-returns-empty-list/44555406?noredirect=1#comment76101638_44555406):

> If you use the network tab and look at the document returned it will
>   give you the original state before whoever messes with the DOM.

Comment: this  works, +1 !  I grabbed the same xpath as OP by Google Chrome Developer Tools, can you explain why no tbody?

Comment: if you `print page.content` you notice there is no `tbody` in there. `tbody` is generated by the inspector, which is why it gives you an inaccurate path,

Comment: If you use the network tab and look at the document returned it will give you the original state before whoever messes with the DOM. @HaifengZhang

Comment: @All Thank you all, now I get it!

Comment: Thanks!!!, it actually works!.
(I would rank this answer as "Usefull" but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: why not select it as the answer? @Matnagra

Comment: @All , Done! sorry guys. I am new in this forum and I forgot about it.
Thanks again!